# Objective-C - Cut Image Based on Etched Line Borders

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdpGZ.jpg) of a UIWebView with all the images on the page having a bright red, etched border. I'd like to know how I could go about cutting this screenshot into smaller images based on the borders. For example, the google page would have just the logo and the small location indicator. Are there any image analysis libraries that I would need to look into? Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: The border can be changed to etched or solid and to any color needed.

Comment: I dont think so that you will find any library exactly doing this but take a look at gpu image library it has feature wich detect specific color..comdine it with your crop algo ...you have a very good problem at hand

Comment: Thanks amar. I'll look into GPUImage and see what I can pull together there.

Comment: Maybe this would be easier if you had javascript check elements for the border color, then grabbed the image URL from there?

Comment: I'm able to do that, but there are certain inaccuracies that occur when trying to detect the element's boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code since I am also doing to same thing for Image cropping from UIWebview :

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);

[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

CGRect rect = **your cropping CGREct**;

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([viewImage CGImage], rect);

UIImage *imgRect = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

hope this will help you

Comment: I specifically need to identify the etched-lines that as logos so I can cut those portions up into pieces.